# Laplace distribution in a linear model

Tags: probability, statistics

I've encountered this question in my studies -
$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^{p}  X_{ji}B_j +e_i$
where $e_i \sim \text{Laplace}(0,m)$ where $m$ is unknown.

I am asked to find the density and distribution of $Y$, the expectation.
I'm unsure how to do this - I've never dealt with this before, so would love some help.
Thanks

Comment: I have edited your question, hopefully I did not change anything in your question.

Comment: It's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Do you have $Y_i = \text{Laplace}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}  X_{ji}B_j,m\right)$ ?

Comment: @Henry It's not given to me but I am supposed to find the density and distribution. Is that it? How would i go about finding it?

Comment: This is missing details. Are the $e_i$'s independent? Are $X_{ji},B_j$ fixed constants?

Comment: @StubbornAtom ei's are iid. Unsure about the rest - This is in a regression and statistical modelling course so I assume they are.

Comment: If they are, then $y_i$'s are independent $\text{Laplace}\left(\sum_{j=1}^{p}  X_{ji}B_j,m\right)$ as Henry mentioned.

Comment: @StubbornAtom is it because yi is a sum of a laplace + a constant?

Comment: Yes, just derive the distribution of $X+c$ where $c$ is a constant and $X$ is Laplace.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you.